# How does Outlook determine if there are extra line breaks?

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, text-formatting

Outlook 2010 (32-bit) / Windows 7

I have a scenario where a plain-text email message is being interpreted incorrectly by Outlook and formatted strangely.

On all other email clients, the message looks like this:

```
--------------------------
Foo Title:
--------------------------
Foo 1 #: 123456789
Foo 2 ID: ref:_123456._789101112wD:ref
Foo Date: 1/11/2014
Foo Category: Blah
Foo Category 2: Blah 2
Foo Summary: Blah
--------------------------
```

For some reason though, Outlook 2010 on my system states ("Extra line breaks in this message were removed" and displays the message body like:

```
--------------------------
Foo Title:
--------------------------
Foo 1 #: 123456789
Foo 2 ID: ref:_123456._789101112wD:ref Foo Date: 1/11/2014
Foo Category: Blah
Foo Category 2: Blah 2
Foo Summary: Blah
--------------------------
```

This is all plain-text - no HTML formatting so I'm not sure how/where Outlook is thinking that there's an extra line break.  Can someone elaborate on what's going on here?  How does Outlook determine that there are extra line breaks?

I know I can change my Outlook preferences but I'd prefer to figure out what's happening here since this email will go to other folks too.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but I think it may be important to note that the line that messed up line breaks had 3 colons in it. This may be your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Can someone elaborate on what's going on here? How does Outlook determine that there are extra line breaks?"

> By default, the Auto Remove Line Breaks feature in Outlook is enabled. This causes the line breaks to be removed. Any two or more successive line breaks are not removed.

Source: [Line breaks are removed in posts made in plain text format in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816)

I've run into this myself in the past as well.  The "fix" I used was to change the source email (mine were generated by a utility I wrote) and indent each line with a couple spaces, and magically Outlook would stop trying to unwrap them.

According to [this blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20120505102344/http://scottonwriting.com/sowblog/archive/2009/12/08/163373.aspx), and [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1220479/2176064.aspx) you may also be able to prevent the unwrap by appending a single extra space on the END of each line as well/instead. :)

Comment: With Outlook 2010 I need no less than 3 trailing spaces to workaround extra line break detection. This workaround is welcome as I can't expect every email recipient to change their Outlook settings.